# How can I smooth a 3D surface generated by RegionBoundary?

Tags: interpolation, regions, approximation

I have a set of points that belong to the surface of an object. I would like to approximate a surface to which I can compute the distance. of other points. With the nice code of [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/86196/how-do-i-create-a-triangulated-surface-from-points/86277#86277) post, I was able to reconstruct a `RegionBoundary` that already looks quite good and to which I can compute distances using the function `RegionDistance`. However, I would like to smooth the surface prior to that a little to get rid of the triangulation effect. Is that possible in *Mathematica*?

Here is my code so far:

```
points={{332.503, 164.196, 141.151}, {348.923, 51.3424,
313.257},  {490.391, 
  392.449, 467.328}, {363.68, 708.575, 494.249}, {243.736, 650.65, 
  605.863}, {167.854, 502.522, 289.97}, {395.992, 673.63, 
  412.396}, {442.32, 161.375, 243.053}, {390.402, 565.375, 
  335.89}, {358.569, 511.312, 623.592}, {365.236, 589.126, 
  331.892}, {429.451, 717.615, 532.707}, {413.034, 710.258, 
  586.691}, {417.364, 718.47, 533.964}, {213.105, 390.563, 
  111.511}, {464.4, 496.675, 611.62}, {413.343, 167.916, 
  198.667}, {376.796, 122.681, 407.362}, {522.351, 541.699, 
  596.626}, {125.383, 119.593, 201.679}, {126.66, 624.233, 
  492.103}, {482.833, 221.833, 369.833}, {323.5, 490.5, 
  601.5}, {326.623, 487.503, 203.405}, {85.1852, 408.238, 
  227.059}, {164.74, 128.175, 150.482}, {199.011, 163.751, 
  400.412}, {346.473, 358.464, 134.96}, {417.547, 386.164, 
  211.435}, {188.618, 121.412, 360.212}, {435.274, 250.289, 
  175.814}, {428.463, 412.995, 548.872}, {186.597, 102.459, 
  336.316}, {522.096, 552.907, 483.329}, {337.035, 175.359, 
  449.416}, {471.617, 197.544, 370.303}, {163.591, 459.144, 
  472.713}, {419.946, 513.294, 463.35}, {324.831, 652.026, 
  617.843}, {184.788, 85.4434, 321.505}, {548.535, 580.905, 
  576.198}, {134.656, 128.965, 172.655}, {237.601, 660.164, 
  590.487}, {284.022, 524.141, 353.107}, {98.8513, 261.728, 
  371.092}, {190.68, 72.2024, 248.625}, {161.724, 263.452, 
  98.6433}, {262.144, 484.765, 187.801}, {162.9, 96.6219, 
  200.596}, {132., 530.5, 455.5}, {507.442, 668.656, 
  486.154}, {274.478, 52.2563, 244.109}, {134.926, 116.117, 
  303.853}, {306.965, 400.445, 125.187}, {324.457, 149.309, 
  419.615}, {399.676, 493.375, 315.875}, {179.869, 253.322, 
  436.796}, {533.897, 546.518, 581.324}, {295.663, 202.435, 
  102.079}, {376.439, 698.222, 580.886}, {449.935, 516.316, 
  368.132}, {459.096, 152.561, 324.066}, {470.669, 620.348, 
  678.3}, {462.584, 464.429, 314.114}, {282.712, 713.11, 
  562.706}, {152.318, 92.9758, 274.162}, {271.539, 583.09, 
  301.286}, {268.328, 249.024, 88.3681}, {216.507, 431.065, 
  130.987}, {423.833, 615.5, 665.}, {380.322, 67.781, 
  320.736}, {318.34, 644.74, 372.886}, {469.088, 247.028, 
  445.556}, {540.019, 663.612, 550.982}, {473.462, 220.243, 
  406.216}, {454.349, 722.933, 522.013}, {66.3225, 346.62, 
  305.46}, {533.978, 597.711, 660.508}, {530.985, 664.202, 
  654.597}, {309.46, 195.999, 108.85}, {340.974, 340.319, 
  552.639}, {422.508, 377.664, 531.371}, {176.511, 76.1966, 
  258.702}, {316.864, 539.726, 250.176}, {452.391, 332.543, 
  217.13}, {77.5253, 291.832, 344.741}, {65.3084, 219.931, 
  261.025}, {492.609, 282.219, 421.681}, {423.923, 541.281, 
  654.475}, {396.524, 271.286, 514.397}, {199.764, 465.467, 
  164.648}, {483.527, 684.076, 669.594}, {334.622, 83.9542, 
  367.422}, {447.46, 517.391, 320.083}, {313.744, 476.67, 
  288.196}, {456.043, 372.201, 497.113}, {452.812, 717.343, 
  639.122}, {182.871, 129.579, 366.947}, {512.744, 708.845, 
  570.144}, {398.484, 643.825, 389.497}, {338.041, 397.561, 
  148.824}, {430.163, 449.935, 271.511}, {178.483, 230.622, 
  429.226}, {133.231, 439.313, 178.045}, {291.368, 37.5505, 
  281.138}, {228.961, 619.735, 356.996}, {255.153, 252.441, 
  90.1935}, {177.16, 262.151, 93.7874}, {435.71, 409.946, 
  536.079}, {291.048, 710.772, 536.598}, {128.35, 160.9, 
  329.05}, {217.215, 158.286, 416.479}, {98.3773, 353.148, 
  395.072}, {161.267, 151.325, 132.306}, {299.199, 704.953, 
  483.595}, {208.218, 89.8083, 171.227}, {155.932, 360.6, 
  113.962}, {377.542, 329.434, 139.294}, {133.498, 289.179, 
  115.104}, {144.267, 209.748, 384.628}, {337.605, 95.1021, 
  195.829}, {398.332, 526.418, 282.529}, {129.582, 195.206, 
  343.11}, {384.721, 155.192, 431.878}, {502.508, 372.431, 
  437.695}, {183.25, 372.725, 105.853}, {79.5506, 309.299, 
  177.712}, {271.535, 599.345, 322.607}, {484.1, 563.99, 
  659.884}, {380.897, 62.2556, 306.81}, {332.349, 452.716, 
  178.931}, {321.748, 281.535, 533.936}, {486.052, 478.483, 
  558.862}, {73.247, 335.451, 357.876}, {129.021, 461.992, 
  323.019}, {456.977, 541.183, 343.661}, {204.329, 445.22, 
  140.278}, {64.0611, 333.507, 222.09}, {182.534, 455.538, 
  165.295}, {409.577, 541.794, 458.832}, {305.333, 389.861, 
  122.394}, {114.483, 213.57, 355.812}, {419.16, 94.7074, 
  290.175}, {492.161, 671.952, 468.522}, {491., 340.5, 
  375.5}, {190.721, 473.554, 174.632}, {136.751, 312.101, 
  112.785}, {459.361, 161.687, 315.93}, {407.247, 653.559, 
  403.558}, {186.03, 602.83, 562.473}, {334.885, 108.839, 
  174.74}, {246.925, 474.024, 166.894}, {281.17, 149.913, 
  418.593}, {397.248, 95.3347, 356.886}, {394.297, 696.328, 
  453.213}, {500.71, 705.105, 508.737}, {412.611, 694.597, 
  448.127}, {294.526, 594.958, 626.525}, {64.4193, 256.905, 
  315.282}, {452.617, 355.839, 491.916}, {341.5, 277.5, 
  339.5}, {178.243, 513.525, 304.626}, {422.617, 431.838, 
  246.101}, {166.68, 204.558, 98.5556}, {493.511, 334.357, 
  398.033}, {535.079, 573.321, 528.362}, {99.2974, 228.613, 
  355.421}, {479.43, 304.942, 377.161}, {74.7139, 264.505, 
  332.803}, {215.939, 687.911, 552.374}, {126.787, 360.173, 
  138.291}, {237.003, 463.761, 157.922}, {220.743, 275.657, 
  478.56}, {540.747, 590.994, 617.299}, {457.626, 690.456, 
  668.88}, {346.502, 563.064, 631.524}, {371.636, 604.184, 
  326.928}, {387.425, 365.146, 331.925}, {157.388, 436.461, 
  465.652}, {254.299, 625.72, 616.211}, {208.19, 59.1733, 
  260.456}, {431.631, 236.662, 175.146}, {505.25, 714.826, 
  561.175}, {343.983, 108.241, 186.74}, {191.833, 341.325, 
  101.09}, {398.674, 520.09, 639.57}, {464.716, 487.783, 
  317.067}, {281.041, 469.01, 565.012}, {142.306, 360.143, 
  438.263}, {351.655, 247.073, 519.403}, {170.277, 88.3455, 
  216.392}, {413.748, 402.202, 549.435}, {458.967, 206.176, 
  274.538}, {416.928, 215.009, 173.625}, {537.722, 558.167, 
  569.611}, {315.152, 106.21, 164.028}, {533.505, 689.304, 
  600.623}, {479.376, 222.006, 389.264}, {264.487, 425.758, 
  131.793}, {225.421, 328.948, 99.5791}, {261.952, 673.365, 
  413.775}, {195.493, 103.461, 355.152}, {231.74, 572.119, 
  594.118}, {140.627, 475.714, 449.734}, {359.23, 710.85, 
  507.043}, {262.531, 444.415, 546.021}, {185.498, 323.012, 
  96.9038}, {224.533, 203.809, 85.3744}, {437.381, 324.328, 
  491.04}, {480.57, 433.744, 362.794}, {355.361, 67.347, 
  336.442}, {217.99, 391.647, 515.415}, {540.946, 617.038, 
  567.645}, {502.332, 573.604, 659.474}, {374.332, 432.322, 
  587.396}, {463.168, 480.326, 590.313}, {394.63, 467.399, 
  603.823}, {264.35, 403.419, 117.151}, {346.891, 597.698, 
  313.165}, {169.98, 672.394, 528.013}, {362.997, 558.273, 
  286.68}, {476.326, 449.697, 528.007}, {413.973, 145.108, 
  412.639}, {409.848, 594.467, 665.}, {450.982, 442.75, 
  288.465}, {301.072, 434.966, 155.1}, {285.826, 699.773, 
  478.549}, {252.641, 669.257, 594.078}, {125.053, 533.84, 
  399.501}, {396.53, 364.873, 177.542}, {230.073, 537.97, 
  580.132}, {206.656, 244.125, 446.061}, {375.37, 593.391, 
  350.296}, {74.0148, 236.789, 182.9}, {291.077, 490.511, 
  193.363}, {286.015, 291.667, 97.3073}, {149.436, 544.798, 
  499.933}, {323.634, 684.378, 593.344}, {368.638, 519.239, 
  256.217}, {242.973, 504.349, 555.061}, {301.526, 326.531, 
  545.819}, {378.5, 250.5, 517.5}, {160.564, 93.2396, 
  236.522}, {303.995, 217.386, 487.886}, {226.711, 329.956, 
  504.41}, {426.731, 146.269, 388.805}, {294.901, 514.185, 
  593.423}, {398.014, 213.422, 162.224}, {136.987, 309.181, 
  424.141}, {485.625, 434.403, 506.073}, {230.109, 170.578, 
  96.7482}, {465.5, 332.026, 278.395}, {336.793, 412.442, 
  164.347}, {202.985, 150.554, 116.793}, {351.931, 545.145, 
  413.645}, {343.885, 211.189, 485.308}, {122.871, 588.535, 
  433.515}, {187.455, 91.3415, 184.823}, {166.521, 416.539, 
  470.903}, {204.11, 593.06, 574.68}, {265.075, 594.426, 
  619.541}, {452.063, 246., 201.813}, {465.412, 237.152, 
  297.139}, {240.944, 106.154, 381.972}, {353.572, 447.899, 
  586.648}, {522.052, 557.929, 493.308}, {311.55, 429.929, 
  357.58}, {319.981, 241.79, 511.625}, {476.672, 319.88, 
  347.519}, {238.982, 559.259, 596.398}, {399.093, 69.3107, 
  291.765}, {169.397, 549.109, 521.505}, {470.536, 193.502, 
  352.944}, {317.966, 47.6604, 322.474}, {143.012, 486.259, 
  350.939}, {420.848, 227.378, 472.659}, {404.146, 369.319, 
  540.621}, {64.1053, 355.509, 246.877}, {147.585, 489.587, 
  476.16}, {458.526, 352.185, 248.103}, {206.466, 320.92, 
  89.4909}, {434.343, 481.018, 296.823}, {526.201, 698.731, 
  589.809}, {411.551, 553.276, 457.865}, {291.794, 192.563, 
  99.4244}, {203.358, 221.116, 83.4906}, {440.474, 163.383, 
  386.538}, {263.945, 625.913, 622.092}, {489.832, 285.927, 
  405.232}, {382.544, 117.677, 199.491}, {428.025, 184.286, 
  442.893}, {120.932, 415.094, 172.843}, {481.989, 613.07, 
  411.532}, {168.744, 675.017, 464.142}, {114.266, 578.017, 
  436.803}, {69.718, 336.308, 336.153}, {91.5466, 356.125, 
  381.752}, {142.674, 315.79, 434.314}, {384.731, 703.292, 
  568.911}, {289.231, 500.734, 585.946}, {207.223, 283.139, 
  81.2631}, {281.496, 254.194, 85.6419}, {355.967, 109.122, 
  394.74}, {136.192, 540.732, 383.402}, {316.21, 313.956, 
  540.89}, {470.587, 526.275, 634.853}, {412.395, 181.916, 
  452.023}, {426.78, 172.23, 211.919}, {507.751, 568.654, 
  426.941}, {149.569, 623.632, 521.702}, {522.053, 596.565, 
  504.43}, {445.641, 705.644, 649.868}, {500.051, 406.023, 
  475.83}, {105.289, 339.366, 139.709}, {222.8, 503.209, 
  545.567}, {297.5, 643.5, 376.5}, {463.572, 302.651, 
  294.815}, {415.034, 435.488, 575.195}, {498.5, 360.5, 
  400.}, {367.731, 76.8686, 228.275}, {436.326, 205.537, 
  203.732}, {108.407, 435.677, 301.792}, {387.129, 144.66, 
  425.169}, {148.846, 512.783, 363.248}, {294.524, 651.253, 
  615.102}, {276.824, 704.882, 511.993}, {508.925, 697.127, 
  510.355}, {141.179, 414.772, 152.592}, {150.37, 567.084, 
  509.542}, {84.3222, 302.445, 373.23}, {273.708, 41.1934, 
  279.497}, {485.783, 687.985, 472.139}, {418.472, 586.365, 
  350.806}, {386.808, 215.734, 488.399}, {126.574, 496.53, 
  407.109}, {303.003, 654.552, 404.317}, {388.631, 170.323, 
  178.592}, {60.4691, 336.622, 241.461}, {428.305, 674.971, 
  665.598}, {518.182, 700.236, 638.253}, {88.6092, 377.561, 
  191.29}, {423.423, 624.851, 666.516}, {240.297, 398.662, 
  532.676}, {523.881, 581.634, 492.541}, {449.386, 135.94, 
  284.265}, {439.936, 449.785, 566.978}, {414.277, 640.763, 
  387.472}, {398.379, 439.852, 302.649}, {484.849, 479.907, 
  424.759}, {440.677, 121.274, 295.239}, {416.527, 267.518, 
  156.597}, {401.412, 246.088, 496.816}, {100.868, 301.862, 
  145.398}, {164.918, 555.291, 338.842}, {226.951, 86.2575, 
  169.979}, {270.096, 429.629, 556.755}, {324.274, 302.205, 
  538.657}, {505.481, 638.917, 682.089}, {445.715, 307.064, 
  475.054}, {325.905, 527.296, 301.779}, {447.016, 549.909, 
  654.356}, {315.762, 262.642, 97.9202}, {465.574, 636.244, 
  424.755}, {322.15, 44.2332, 297.187}, {144.483, 569.34, 
  381.592}, {476.269, 435.466, 338.904}, {152.225, 250.834, 
  105.101}, {147.297, 646.674, 439.411}, {179.087, 75.9104, 
  234.857}, {200.5, 643.783, 581.387}, {398.5, 637.5, 
  660.5}, {317.109, 376.517, 122.095}, {279.5, 620.5, 
  331.5}, {450.519, 499.27, 620.204}, {328.457, 544.796, 
  407.331}, {182.109, 681.355, 535.461}, {493.527, 268.575, 
  406.779}, {82.5982, 257.48, 172.835}, {350.153, 338.745, 
  119.873}, {400.21, 550.948, 333.729}, {120.346, 465.473, 
  249.646}, {465.946, 654.168, 434.657}, {401.335, 80.3895, 
  269.898}, {538.983, 677.564, 597.956}, {58.3805, 232.11, 
  272.752}, {453.374, 382.883, 263.261}, {82.5445, 281.768, 
  359.469}, {446.729, 558.359, 374.242}, {410.445, 516.859, 
  334.516}, {176.856, 415.792, 482.154}, {436.088, 540.186, 
  324.808}, {196.898, 350.806, 488.46}, {396.196, 545.086, 
  649.558}, {123.005, 591.694, 479.867}, {457.174, 387.679, 
  504.738}, {153.219, 656.382, 523.696}, {59.2334, 295.899, 
  220.902}, {124.963, 121.402, 251.698}, {534.829, 526.5, 
  549.174}, {550.326, 665.396, 593.728}, {339.988, 130.166, 
  168.475}, {536.55, 571.686, 618.421}, {232.326, 59.1984, 
  314.72}, {380.804, 351.925, 547.686}, {276.004, 70.8784, 
  358.826}, {232.793, 123.093, 129.862}, {286.786, 190.997, 
  456.244}, {94.6846, 415.523, 322.478}, {105.193, 140.028, 
  250.066}, {237.678, 169.138, 421.162}, {378.5, 143., 
  185.}, {161.642, 326.999, 444.955}, {482.498, 242.721, 
  379.422}, {224.029, 691.288, 449.137}, {477.435, 654.835, 
  450.421}, {94.5795, 306.593, 386.7}, {468.979, 408.487, 
  501.844}, {423.371, 100.292, 327.401}, {480.5, 465., 
  346.5}, {323.585, 515.242, 230.547}, {459.792, 286.323, 
  260.46}, {62.7555, 308.083, 204.032}, {500.854, 401.473, 
  441.756}, {81.0766, 383.639, 240.022}, {328.847, 52.4033, 
  255.453}, {247.308, 529.708, 241.989}, {396.523, 329.156, 
  140.38}, {373.781, 697.713, 453.124}, {396.283, 510.121, 
  315.124}, {411.984, 672.331, 652.537}, {221.641, 420.895, 
  520.734}, {482.596, 312.939, 354.171}, {343.149, 414.295, 
  435.363}, {298.648, 39.1472, 294.322}, {343.22, 299.867, 
  542.947}, {182.697, 152.604, 117.336}, {138.374, 250.48, 
  112.115}, {375.778, 76.5993, 336.997}, {448.296, 558.052, 
  341.102}, {128.403, 484.19, 394.699}, {438.29, 263.278, 
  471.922}, {344.64, 377.915, 148.744}, {484.255, 711.123, 
  508.443}, {77.4254, 354.931, 194.897}, {168.573, 675.309, 
  484.661}, {93.4348, 263.235, 153.051}, {186.112, 501.935, 
  263.001}, {388.68, 450.638, 293.253}, {229.242, 384.352, 
  523.155}, {323.999, 74.537, 207.705}, {411.458, 388.617, 
  196.079}, {191.506, 216.82, 430.611}, {53.8916, 299.694, 
  281.102}, {126., 457., 330.}, {504.341, 658.829, 575.953}, {293.63, 
  227.978, 498.81}, {300.635, 471.031, 296.168}, {145.753, 195.687, 
  106.72}, {322.311, 406.461, 346.703}, {197.173, 686.613, 
  466.436}, {459., 294.5, 232.}, {78.3771, 182.069, 215.053}, {316.42,
   573.076, 315.042}, {209.413, 612.93, 598.49}, {428.847, 385.819, 
  536.264}, {83.2919, 180.975, 183.579}, {125.706, 275.496, 
  114.538}, {385.373, 166.013, 443.243}, {357.619, 178.287, 
  147.039}, {136.611, 235.835, 390.861}, {191.367, 331.207, 
  470.341}, {85.4225, 403.602, 327.865}, {325.667, 693.033, 
  583.098}, {514.3, 508.9, 468.5}, {379.964, 302.471, 
  136.966}, {425.161, 665.836, 411.877}, {322.001, 493.219, 
  424.654}, {462.658, 176.053, 324.446}, {228.608, 401.169, 
  522.613}, {146.677, 393.634, 135.842}, {390.875, 498.59, 
  626.572}, {489.97, 665.369, 673.809}, {520.1, 457.953, 
  480.554}, {84.5, 386.5, 345.5}, {138.649, 258.408, 
  406.563}, {371.64, 212.815, 494.77}, {307.122, 675.18, 
  597.133}, {247.109, 46.5854, 278.052}, {264.061, 679.727, 
  438.011}, {271.048, 489.114, 570.545}, {216.598, 641.574, 
  369.696}, {499.699, 390.046, 441.895}, {208.416, 402.902, 
  505.952}, {263.147, 713.229, 523.117}, {513.056, 562.495, 
  455.919}, {229.306, 534.749, 294.441}, {499.753, 479.377, 
  428.603}, {104.833, 355.833, 148.5}, {416.21, 487.907, 
  616.249}, {161.197, 101.501, 319.324}};
```

Then I approximate a surface using the code for alpha shapes:

```
surface = RegionBoundary @ alphaShapes[points, 150]
```

> [image]

I checked for `BSplineSurface`, but the function needs a structured array of control points which I do not have. Any ideas how to smooth the surface? Or is there a way to use the function `BSplineSurface` for that?

Comment: I seem to missing something -- the code for `alphaShapes`

Comment: Its here http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/86196/how-do-i-create-a-triangulated-surface-from-points/86277#86277

Comment: I just inserted it as a link to not confuse the question too much.

Comment: `surface` seems to still have interior components: `Show[surface, Axes -> True, ClipPlanes -> {{1, 1, 0, -500}}]`.  -- If you want it merely to look smoother, consider `VertexNormals`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use the undocumented `ReturnMeshObject` method like @Simon Woods used [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/23868/10777) to get `ListSurfacePlot3D` to do the smoothing for you. With this option added, it returns a `GraphicsComplex` ready to be used by `DiscretizeGraphics`.

```
Graphics`Mesh`MeshInit[]; 
mc = MeshCoordinates[surface]; 
extractedmesh = DiscretizeGraphics[
   First@ListSurfacePlot3D[mc, Method -> {"ReturnMeshObject" -> True}, 
     Mesh -> {15, 15, 15}, MaxPlotPoints -> 10]]
```

[image: A new mesh created by hijacking ListSurfacePlot3D]

This returns a new mesh with many more interpolated sample points. One can play with the plotting parameters or directly operate on the new region to get the surface to acceptable smoothness.

As for `BSplineSurface` et al., the approach taken [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/30644/10777) looks good, where @Belisarius chopped the datapoints into *z*-slices, interpolated, and used regular points from the interpolated curves to construct `BSplineFunction`s. I'm presently trying to replicate this and will add that if I succeed.

### Edit: Tweaking parameters

Still no luck making splines work. It shouldn't seem to be as hard as it feels. Does anyone else have the required savoir-faire?

I wanted to add some pictures of how things look with different parameters. Increasing `MaxPlotPoints` too much tends to overfit the points, but that's a matter of taste.

```
 (*Mesh -> 50, MaxPlotPoints -> 15*)
```

[image: Mesh -> 50, MaxPlotPoints -> 15]

```
 (*Mesh -> 50, MaxPlotPoints -> 25*)
```

[image: Mesh -> 50, MaxPlotPoints -> 25]

Comment: Really nice approach, thanks very much! :) Exactly what I was looking for! If it is possible to get the BSplineFunction running, this would also be nice, but the current smoothing already is what I need.

Comment: I'm honored :) Some notes on the ListSurfacePlot3D hack, which you may have already noticed:
- Increasing MaxPlotPoints too much tends to overfit things and make your potato lumpy
- Using MeshFunctions gives you some control over how it's subdivided
- TriangulateMesh[] after the fact refines things very well.
- Iterating this process (setting mc = MeshCoordinates[extractedmesh] and going again) can be quite satisfying.

Comment: Ugh. No line breaks. I'll integrate those tips into the solution text when I have a moment.

Comment: You mean running the smoothing several times and updating mc in each round? I tried some values for MaxPlotPoints. 25 seems to be a good compromise... Would be nice if you would add the info to the answer :)

Comment: Thanks for the updated answer. I am still wondering a little what parameter makes sense to use. I just checked with 25 which gives me somehow reasonable results for many of my datasets, but for some strange artefacts start to occur (probably overfitting as hYPtenuser pointed out).