# VoronoiMesh as a Graph

Tags: graphs-and-networks, computational-geometry, mesh, style, lattices

I want to draw the following graph

[image]

using `VoronoiMesh`. For example, since

```
L = 3;
pts = Flatten[
   Table[{3/2 i, Sqrt[3] j + Mod[i, 2] Sqrt[3]/2}, {i, L + 4}, {j, 
     L + 4}], 1];
mesh0 = VoronoiMesh[pts];
gr = Graph[mesh0["Edges"], 
  VertexCoordinates -> MeshCoordinates[mesh0]]
```

yields

[image]

I thought about "trimming" the Voronoi mesh in the following manner (see [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/212624/creating-a-hexagonal-lattice-with-voronoimesh) for more info)

```
mesh1 = MeshRegion[MeshCoordinates[mesh0], 
   With[{a = PropertyValue[{mesh0, 2}, MeshCellMeasure]}, 
    With[{m = 3}, Pick[MeshCells[mesh0, 2], UnitStep[a - m], 0]]]];
mesh = MeshRegion[MeshCoordinates[mesh1], MeshCells[mesh1, {2, "Interior"}]]
```

[image]

However, when using either `mesh["Edges"]` or `mesh["Coordinates"]` for this `mesh`, I get the following error

[image]

Any idea why?

Regarding the mesh coordinates, I can solve it using `MeshCoordinates[mesh]` instead. However, I cannot get the connectivity needed to build the graph. Somehow, `MeshRegion` used in this way seems to lose (or change) some of its properties. I've also tried, using something like (from [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/23807/converting-mesh-in-densityplot-to-a-graph))

```
gvoronoi = 
 AdjacencyGraph[mesh["AdjacencyMatrix"], 
  VertexCoordinates -> MeshCoordinates[mesh]]
```

but with no success. Any ideas?

Additionally, if you have any better suggestions regarding building a graph like this, for any `L`, please feel free to share!

Comment: Clearly this is not a case where you can use the *undocumented* functionality. Thus, `Graph[UndirectedEdge @@@ MeshCells[mesh, 1][[All, 1]], VertexCoordinates -> MapIndexed[First[#2] -> #1 &, MeshCoordinates[mesh]]]`.

Comment: As I remember you said that you only want to use built-in functions so that they can be used with the Wolfram Player. I posted an answer with IGraph/M as it may be useful for future visitors as well.

Comment: Yes, that is correct. Thank you anyway, I'll probably start using IGraph/M for future WolframPlayer-independent projects. Seems @J.M.isinlimbo's comment does the trick without it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
L = 3;
pts = Flatten[Table[{3/2 i, Sqrt[3] j + Mod[i, 2] Sqrt[3]/2}, {i, L + 4}, {j, L + 4}], 1];

mesh0 = VoronoiMesh[pts];
mr0 = DiscretizeGraphics[Select[MeshPrimitives[mesh0, 2], 
    RegionWithin[Rectangle @@ Transpose[CoordinateBounds[pts]], #] &]];

el0 = MeshCells[mr0, 1] /. Line -> Apply[UndirectedEdge];
vc0 = MeshCoordinates[mr0];

Show[mesh0, Graph[el0, VertexCoordinates -> vc0, EdgeStyle -> Thick]]
```

[image]

Slightly more convenient approach is to provide the coordinate bounds in the second argument of `VoronoiMesh` and discretize the interior polygons:

```
mesh1 = VoronoiMesh[pts, CoordinateBounds[pts]];

mr1 = DiscretizeGraphics[MeshPrimitives[mesh1, {2, "Interior"}]];

el1 = MeshCells[mr1, 1] /. Line -> Apply[UndirectedEdge];
vc1 = MeshCoordinates[mr1];

Show[mesh1, 
 Graph[el1, VertexCoordinates -> vc1, EdgeStyle -> Thick]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

With [IGraph/M](http://szhorvat.net/mathematica/IGraphM), you can use

```
IGLatticeMesh["Hexagonal", Rectangle[{0, 0}, {2, 4}]]
```

[image]

`IGLatticeMesh` first fills the region `Rectangle[{0, 0}, {2, 4}]` with lattice points, then places a unit mesh cell at each lattice point. You can use a different region to obtain a different overall shape. Keep in mind that it is not the mesh that is being cropped to this region, but only the points that define the locations of unit cells.

```
IGMeshGraph[%]
```

[image]